# Mongodb partitioning collection divided into 12 collection within a database

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using mongoDB as a backend. The collection which I have 1B documents and more, I want to Partitioning the collection to 12month collection. JanCollection , FebCollection .... based on Month_of_sale as a key. How can we create a 12 collection as a chunks within a database.

In this case, WE can use 12 different collection on db. and Insert and update the document on that collection based on MonthOfSale. For example. If the MonthOfSale is 2, insert/update into the FebCollection. If we search data, There also we find the document on particular collection by MonthOfSale. My question is Any other efficient way to handle this situation in php and MongoDB.

Comment: I'd go with the recommended procedure from the users manual. What did _you_ try so far?

Comment: According to the QA on site (this has been asked about prevously), there is no partitioning in MongoDB yet, the feature is requested thought ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46450166/367456))

Comment: In this case, WE can use 12 different collection on db. and Insert and update the document on that collection based on MonthOfSale. For example. If the MonthOfSale is 2, insert/update into the FebCollection. If we search data, There also we find the document on particular collection by MonthOfSale. My question is Any other efficient way to handle this situation in php and MongoDB.

Comment: Yes, however, what is efficient or not is in the eye of the beholder and can't be answered (in the meaning of a good fit here on site). The reference I've provided contains some suggestions IIRC and you also may find further  referenced Q&A material there dealing with that question. At least for faster results to your question I'd go with these. Maybe you can turn it towards an answerable question then. More tips are in the [help], e.g. how to make it a reproducible example etc. .